# Shell loops using non-integers?

Tags: bash, scripting, loops, sh

I wrote a .sh file to compile and run a few programs for a homework assignment. I have a "for" loop in the script, but it won't work unless I use only integers:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=10; i<=100000; i+=100))
do
    ./hw3_2_2 $i
done
```

The variable $i is an input for the program hw3_2_2, and I have non-integer values I'd like to use. How could I loop through running the code with a list of decimal numbers?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I find it surprising that in five years no one ever mentioned the utility created just for generating ranges, but, then again, it comes from BSD around 2005, and perhaps it wasn't even generally available on Linux at the time the question was made.

But here it is:

```
for i in $(seq 0 0.1 1)
```

Or, to print all numbers with the same width (by prepending or appending zeroes), use `-w`. That helps prevent numbers being sent as "integers", if that would cause issues.

The syntax is `seq [first [incr]] last`, with `first` defaulting to 1, and `incr` defaulting to either 1 or -1, depending on whether `last` is greater than or less than `first`. For other parameters, see [seq(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq).

Comment: Hi Daniel, is there a way to increment this x.x.x in for loop? For e.g            for i in $(seq 1.0.20  0.0.1  1.0.24). Or is there a way to increment this version# and add it to a list so that I can use it in for loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to just list them:

```
for a in 1.2 3.4 3.11 402.12 4.2 2342.40
do
  ./hw3_2_2 $a
done
```

If the list is huge, so you can't have it as a literal list, consider dumping it in a file and then using something like

```
for a in $(< my-numbers.txt)
do
  ./hw3_2_2 $a
done
```

The $(< my-numbers.txt) part is an efficient way (in Bash) to substitute the contents of the names file in that location of the script. Thanks to Dennis Williamson for pointing out that there is no need to use the external `cat` command for this.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. In Bash: `$(< file)`, in `sh` (and Bash): `while read a; do ...; done < file`

Answer (score 9):

you can use awk to generate your decimals eg steps of`0.1`

```
num=$(awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10;i+=0.1)print i}')
for n in $num
do
  ./hw3_2_2 $n
done
```

or you can do it entirely in awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{cmd="hw3_2_2";for(i=1;i<=10;i+=0.1){c=cmd" "i;system(cmd) } }'
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use floating point in loops like that because if you keep adding 0.1 to 1 you will never get to 10. The counter will go from something like 9.9999999999999822 to 10.099999999999982.

Comment: have you tried it ? pls try and then tell me if it will get to 10.

Comment: If you change the `<=10` to `<10` you would expect the output to change, right? Does it?

Comment: what do you mean expect output to change? it will stop whether you put `<` or `<=`.

Comment: The problem here is inconsistency between the imprecisely represented step and precisely-represented one: if you use `<10` instead of `<=10`, then you'll get 10 for the step of `0.1`, but won't get it for the step like `0.125`, although, if we were working with decimals, we'd avoid 10 in both cases, as the operator `<` implies.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way. You can use a here doc to include your data in the script:

```
read -r -d '' data <<EOF
1.1
2.12
3.14159
4
5.05
EOF

for i in "$data"
do
    ./hw3_2_2 "$i"
done
```

Similarly:

```
array=(
1.1
2.12
3.14159
4
5.05
)

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    ./hw3_2_2 "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually also use "seq" as per the second answer, but just to give an answer in terms of a precision-robust integer loop and then bc conversion to a float:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for i in {2..10..2} ; do 
  x=`echo "scale=2 ; ${i}/10" | bc`
  echo $x
done
```

gives:

.2
.4
.6
.8
1.0

Answer (score 0):

bash doesn't do decimal numbers. Either use something like `bc` that can, or move to a more complete programming language. Beware of [accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) though.