# BASH: iterate over a list of floating numbers in decrement

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

What I want to do is something similar to the python codes beneath, while the variables start, end, and spacing could all be float numbers and start > end.

```
for i in numpy.arange(start, stop, step): 
    print i
```

Or,

```
for i in numpy.linspace(start, stop, num):
    print i
```

I know **awk** is handy (see the second answer in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472191/shell-loops-using-non-integers)).

```
num=$(awk "BEGIN{for(i=${start};i>=${stop};i-=${step})print i}")   
for n in $num 
do 
  Do Something With $n 
done
```

But, how to realize the iteration over a list of floating numbers in decrement in Bash without using awk?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `seq`

```
seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
```